# Unable to connect to SQL Server from RHEL Server 7.4 using Kerberos

Tags: linux, sql-server, redhat, kerberos

So I'm trying to connect to one of our SQL server from a RHEL Server 7.4 machine, I already installed kerberos, unixodbc and Microsoft ODBC for Linux.

The SQL Server I'm trying to connect to is inside Active Directory domain, I was able to authenticate through that using `kinit` but still getting `SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.` error.

This is my snippet from terminal:

```
[RH@localhost /]$ sudo kinit rh@ADS.LOCAL.COM
[sudo] password for RH: 
Password for rh@ADS.LOCAL.COM: 
[RH@localhost /]$ sqlcmd -E -S MyServer
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

This is my `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes
 default_realm = ADS.LOCAL.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
 dns_lookup_kdc = true

[domain_realm]
 .ads.local.com = ADS.LOCAL.COM
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what did you get from

```
klist -k
```

executed as root? If there is nothing to see, then your server is not joined to the active directory. Otherwise you see your host entries for the kerberos system.

Normally, RHEL 7 Systems are configured with sssd as the central authentication service.
Please check if sssd is installed and running:

```
systemctl status sssd
```

If not, you can try to join again with

```
net ads join
```

Otherwise, configure your sssd to join your active directory domain with

```
realm join
```

You can get more Information about this here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/SSSD-AD

Regards,
Björn

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think there would be a security flaw or issue when I join a Linux server to a Windows AD?

Comment: No, this is common practice. If you set on standard software from the main distributions, this will work without more security issues than on windows systems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the solution in my case was having tried to use SQL Server IP rather than the FQDN. Using FQDN fixes this the same error message ("SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database"), or including: "ServerSPN = MSSQLSvc/:" in the ODBC DSN.